# Are those code snippets and file paths in a C++ binary some sort of standard debug information?

Tags: ida, c++, debugging-symbols

This C++ binary has code snippets and paths to sourcecode files everywhere, which is probably some sort of debug info.

- Is this something standard? (Is this RTTI)
- If so, how is this called?
- Are there plugins/tools to help with this?

[image: IDA Screenshot of debug info]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It has the fingerprint of an `assert`:

1. it's called directly after a test;
2. it uses a number -- probably a *source line number* --, a string which points to a file name -- the *source file* -- and a string that describes an error condition;
3. it does not return. (Can be inferred because the inspected value would lead to an erronous situation if the called function returned.)

`assert` is a standard function in most (if not outright all!) standard libraries, and so if your decompiler could recognize which compiler was used, it would have assigned a standard label to `sub_6E0D40`. Since it didn't, you could trace that address and see if (a) it jumps immediately to an external routine such as Windows' native `Assert`, or (b) does what an assert does: outputting the error and immediately exiting.

---

Addition: using the stack plus registers ecx and edx seem to indicate this sub is declared "Microsoft `__fastcall`" ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_fastcall)).

Comment: sub_6E0D40 is __fastcall, not __stdcall. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_fastcall

Comment: @JasonGeffner: you're right, my (wrong) ref said ecx and edx are "designated for use within the function", which is quite the opposite. Edited.